# Threading a function-PyQt GUI

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, subprocess, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am having an issue trying to make my program not freeze when a function is called by a button click. The function opens a .bat file using subprocess.Popen, but while the .bat is running, it freezes my entire GUI, i'd like for user to be able to still use the GUI. I'm pretty new to threading. I do understand threading is one solution for this, but I am uncertain how I make a thread that calls this function whenever a button is clicked. Keep in mind my function is inside a QtDesigner created window. Any ideas or ways I can fix this issue? Maybe lead me to somewhere where I can find an answer?

**Main class name:**

class Ui_TestClass(object):

**My function:**

```
  def runprogram(self):
    dir = self.cwdList[-1]
    test = os.listdir(dir)
    for item in test:
        if item.endswith('.OUT'):
            os.remove(join(dir, item))
    new, ok = QInputDialog.getText(None, "Case Name","Type in a case name to run. (No Spaces) \nOn file dialog, choose file to rename.")
    if (ok):
        newcase = new
    changename =  str(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Choose file', '{0}'.format(self.cwdList[-1]), 'Text files (*.ZCSP*)')[0])
    shutil.move(changename, '{0}\{1}.ZCSP'.format(self.cwdList[-1], newcase))
    self.replaceText('{0}.ZCSP'.format(newcase))
    with open('Test.bat', "w") as runname:
        run = 'ZCSP {0}.ZCSP {0}.OUT'.format(newcase, newcase)
        runname.write(run)
    process = subprocess.Popen([r"{0}\Test.bat".format(self.cwdList[-1])])
    process.wait()
```

self.cwdList is just a list of directories

```
t = threading.Thread(target=self.runprogram)
t.start()
```

I've read that this may work, but how would I insert this in my QtDesigner created code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem I think. Just have it so when you press the button it runs a function that spawns a thread to run your program. For example:

```
def buttonFunction(self):
    t = threading.Thread(target=self.runprogram)
    t.start()
```

Then...

```
def runprogram(self):
    process = subprocess.Popen([r"{0}\Test.bat".format(self.cwdList[-1])])
    process.wait()
```

The program runs in the background and functionality of GUI remains.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by simply removing process.wait(). I am still interested in finding a solution on how to use threads with QtDesigner created code.